# Can't register hwnd window

Tags: c++, windows, hwnd

I'm trying to create hwnd window but I get an error when I try to register it.
The error is the MessageBox notification that kicks in if the Register function fails to register the window, I've copied most of the code so I don't really understand what's the problem.
Here's the code, compiled in VS13:

```
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow){

WNDCLASSEX WndClass;
HWND hwnd;
MSG Msg;

hInst = hInstance;

WndClass.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
WndClass.style = WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_MINIMIZEBOX;
WndClass.lpfnWndProc = WindowProcedure;
WndClass.cbClsExtra = 0;
WndClass.cbWndExtra = 0;
WndClass.hInstance = hInstance;
WndClass.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
WndClass.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
WndClass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW);
WndClass.lpszMenuName = NULL;
WndClass.lpszClassName = (LPCWSTR)gszClassName;
WndClass.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);

if (!RegisterClassEx(&WndClass)){
    MessageBox(NULL, L"Unable to register window", L"Error", MB_ICONSTOP | MB_OK);
    return 0;
}

hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
    WS_EX_STATICEDGE,
    L"MyMainClass",
    L"Try v2.0",
    WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_MINIMIZEBOX,
    CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
    500, 400,
    NULL, NULL,
    hInstance,
    NULL);

if (hwnd == NULL){
    MessageBox(NULL, L"Unable to create window", L"Error", MB_ICONSTOP | MB_OK);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When a system function like `RegisterClassEx` fails, you should use [`GetLastError`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the error code.

Comment: If the function fails, the return value is zero. To get extended error information, call GetLastError, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633587(v=vs.85).aspx - Did you do that? What result did you get?

Comment: Good advice in general, of course, but there's a 99% chance it's going to say "invalid parameter", which won't be of much help here. It should have been rather obvious.

Answer (score 2):

```
WndClass.style = WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_MINIMIZEBOX;
```

This is your problem. According to the [`WNDCLASSEX` docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633577%28v=vs.85%29.aspx),

> style
>   The class style(s). This member can be any combination of the [Class Styles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633574%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#class_styles).

Following that Class Styles link, we get this:

> The class styles define additional elements of the window class. Two or more styles can be combined by using the bitwise OR (|) operator. To assign a style to a window class, assign the style to the style member of the WNDCLASSEX structure. For a list of class styles, see [Window Class Styles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff729176%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

And following that link, we get a list of valid window class styles. The ones that you're using aren't on that list, unfortunately. I think you probably meant to give those to `CreateWindowEx`'s `dwStyle` parameter, which accepts [these valid window styles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632600%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) per the [`CreateWindowEx` docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632680%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

If it helps clarify things at all, window *class* styles are not the same as window styles.

Comment: Precisely correct. Also suspicious is this code: `(LPCWSTR)gszClassName`. Having to cast to `LPCWSTR` is a giant red flag. You should never have to coerce a string type. If your code won't compile without a cast, then you're doing something wrong—like trying to pass a narrow string to something that accepts a wide string. It's also slightly suspicious that he's using a string literal for the class name when creating the window, instead of the same global variable he's using to register the window class.

Comment: Oh yeah, and `WndClass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW)` should really be `WndClass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1)`. It really would help the asker if he read the linked documentation for `WNDCLASSEX`. :-)

Comment: @CodyGray Excellent points. I'd actually suggest posting that as an answer. If anything, the class name hackery might be more likely to cause issues than invalid window flags (although of course all of op's issues are still issues).

Comment: You did explain things really nicely, the fact is I'm learning from 2 sources, an old book (written 2004) and msdn so I might have mixed things a bit...I wanted to create a window with fixed size, without maximize button and disabled resize option

Comment: An old book shouldn't be a problem when it comes to the Windows API. The basics have changed little or at all since 2004. Anyone who is serious about learning Windows API programming should really get ahold of Charles Petzold's [Programming Windows](http://www.charlespetzold.com/pw5/), though. Excellent resource. Yes, it's old, but like I said, not much has changed. And you can easily find out how to do what you want on MSDN, once you've got the basics down. For example, there's lists of flags along with explanations for what they do. You just have to scan the list for what yo want, @Ante.

Comment: @Ante I'm working on something to help you understand the window-creation process. My Internet is up and down right now, so it might take a few hours to get it done, but I'll ping you once I have it up. Cody's suggestion of just diving into MSDN docs is a good one as well.

Comment: @Ante [This might help you out.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23475019/how-do-i-create-a-window-using-the-windows-api) It's a step-by-step walkthrough of the APIs you'll need to use and how you'll need to set them up.

Comment: Thanks for the effort but I've learned quite a lot in last few days regarding window creation, but I'm sure there'll be stuff I can use for sure, thanks again :)